# How to change top tab header height?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to add large header View above Tab navigator of createMaterialTopTabNavigator. How can I change the top tab header height in react navigation?

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
    tabBarVisible: true,
    headerMode:'screen',
    headerTitle: <TabHeader/>,
    height:50,
    tabBarLabel: () => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        switch (routeName) {
            //
        }
        return <Text>{routeName}</Text>;
    },
}),
animationEnabled: false,
swipeEnabled: true,
...
```

Comment: Can you show a design of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Andrew I need 30% screen from top to be header view and rest to be navigator !